# DevExpress components require ASPxHttpHandlerModule registered in the web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

My friend has created a project in asp.net and I am trying to run one of its '.aspx' pages on my side in Visual Studio 2019 but it is giving me this error when I run the project:

`DevExpress components require ASPxHttpHandlerModule registered in the web.config file.`

**Full exception:**
[image: Exception]

He is using DevExpress controls; I have downloaded DevExpress 20.2 and my web.config is also all set, but when I try to run it's giving me the same error.

Here is my web.config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
          For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
          -->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="devExpress">
            <section name="themes" type="DevExpress.Web.ThemesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v20.2, Version=20.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="compression" type="DevExpress.Web.CompressionConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v20.2, Version=20.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="settings" type="DevExpress.Web.SettingsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v20.2, Version=20.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="errors" type="DevExpress.Web.ErrorsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v20.2, Version=20.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="resources" type="DevExpress.Web.ResourcesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v20.2, Version=20.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Foodcourt" connectionString="Data Source=168.1.35.207,25000;Initial Catalog=db5628_LMHV3;User Id=db5628_frysys;Password=Varykino1a" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxRichEdit.v20.2, Version=20.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
                <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v20.2, Version=20.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
                <add assembly="DevExpress.RichEdit.v20.2.Core, Version=20.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
                <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v20.2, Version=20.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
                <add assembly="DevExpress.Printing.v20.2.Core, Version=20.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
                <add assembly="DevExpress.Office.v20.2.Core, Version=20.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
                <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxSpellChecker.v20.2, Version=20.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
                <add assembly="DevExpress.SpellChecker.v20.2.Core, Version=20.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
                <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v20.2, Version=20.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
                <add assembly="netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
            </assemblies>
            <buildProviders>
                <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
            </buildProviders>
        </compilation>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
        <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
            </namespaces>
            <controls>
                <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
                <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpModules>
            <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v20.2, Version=20.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
        </httpModules>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
            <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v20.2, Version=20.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="DX.ashx" validate="false" />
            <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadProgressHttpHandler, DevExpress.Web.v20.2, Version=20.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="ASPxUploadProgressHandlerPage.ashx" validate="false" />
        </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Drawing.Common" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.1" newVersion="4.0.0.1" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v20.2, Version=20.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
        </modules>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
            <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
            <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v20.2, Version=20.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="DX.ashx" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadProgressHttpHandler, DevExpress.Web.v20.2, Version=20.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="ASPxUploadProgressHandlerPage.ashx" name="ASPxUploadProgressHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <devExpress>
        <themes enableThemesAssembly="true" styleSheetTheme="" theme="" customThemeAssemblies="" baseColor="" font="" />
        <compression enableHtmlCompression="false" enableCallbackCompression="true" enableResourceCompression="true" enableResourceMerging="true" />
        <settings accessibilityCompliant="false" bootstrapMode="" doctypeMode="Html5" rightToLeft="false" checkReferencesToExternalScripts="true" protectControlState="true" ieCompatibilityVersion="edge" />
        <errors callbackErrorRedirectUrl="" />
    </devExpress>

</configuration>
```

Have tried several solutions but none worked. Can anyone tell me what's wrong and what to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issues. Here is the coding which I added in webconfig file.
Kindly check ur DevExpress Version..

<system.webServer>

```
    <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v14.2, Version=14.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
</modules> 
<handlers>
    <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v14.2, Version=14.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" path="DX.ashx" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

</system.webServer>